# How to modify date format column in pandas dataframe to a int using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, pandas, dataframe

Have a df with columns name and exm_date

```
name          exm_date                             
tom       2019-03-05 11:48:03.166              
mark      2018-03-05 11:48:03.166                   
matt      2020-08-05 11:48:03.166                
rob       2020-06-05 11:48:03.166              
chuck     2020-02-05 11:48:03.166               
tom       2020-03-05 11:48:03.166              
matt      2020-02-05 11:48:03.166                 
chuck     2020-06-05 11:48:03.166
```

how to convert the date format in exm_date into a format removing the time stamp and exluding the `-`

expected_output

```
name          exm_date                         code_date    
tom       2019-03-05 11:48:03.166              20190305
mark      2018-03-05 11:48:03.166              20180305     
matt      2020-08-05 11:48:03.166              20200805  
rob       2020-06-05 11:48:03.166              20200605
chuck     2020-02-05 11:48:03.166              20200205 
tom       2020-03-05 11:48:03.166              20200305
matt      2020-02-05 11:48:03.166              20200305    
chuck     2020-06-05 11:48:03.166              20200305
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
import pandas as pd
df['code_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['exm_date']).dt.strftime('%Y%m%d')
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try following code:

```
df['code_date'] = df['exm_date'].apply(lambda x: x.strftime("%Y%d%m"))
```